# Name for cast of Complex type to double

Tags: casting, naming

I have an object (in whatever language) of type Complex, as in complex number.  At a certain point, my program performs a check to see if its imaginary part is zero.  If this is the case, it turns the object into a double and does something with the double.

My question is -- is there a name for that change from Complex to double?  "Downcast" appears to refer to casting to a subclass, which is not quite what is going on here.  Similarly, "Upcast" is typically described as "casting to a superclass", which is likely not quite accurate either -- although it would certainly be possible to implement Complex as a sublcass of double, most languages don't do it that way.

It feels like what I am doing is not so much casting to a superclass as casting to a subset.

EDIT:  I am looking for a general name for the process of taking an object of a type and turning it into an equivalent object of a simpler type.  For example, on another occasion, it might be taking a BigInt and turning into an Int, or even taking a LinearFunction and turning it into a ConstantFunction.

Comment: Second that, it's simply not a cast; it's a extraction.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is -- is there a name for that change from Complex to double?

Yes, what you describe is called "taking the real part", and software commonly uses functions that have names like `get_real(complexnumber)` or, depending on how your language works, just do things like `complexnumber.real`.

Please note that "checking whether something is zero" is a very error prone task with floating point numbers, such as the imaginary and real parts of most complex implementations.